# sudo: pip: command not found in CentOS

Tags: python, centos, pip

I use CentOS and I installed pip to `/usr/local/python-dir/bin/pip`. I made a link to `/usr/local/bin/pip`. Then I executed `sudo pip install xxx`, it reported an error like this:

```
sudo: pip: command not found
```

I see `$PATH` is all right:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

However, I can only execute pip this way:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install xxx
```

How can I configure PATH or something else? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does the link work if you try running it without `sudo`?  Granted, you likely won't have permission to install, but does it try to run `pip` that way?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

For security reasons, `sudo` does not rely on the `$PATH` set in your environment.  There is a `secure_path` option in `/etc/sudoers` that specifies the `PATH` that `sudo` will use for locating binaries.  For example:

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Just add `/usr/local/bin` to this PATH, or get used to typing:

```
sudo `which pip` install xxx
```

Comment: I believe you had to edit the file with visudo: 
sudo visudo; hit insert key, scroll down and make the change, hit esc key, then ':qw' to save the file and exit. That worked for me.

Comment: i agree more with @Paul Kenjora's answer, `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/bin/pip`

Answer (score 11):

Not ideal but works. You can always unlink it after the install to restore security.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip /bin/pip
```

Puts pip in the root path bin.  You can then run pip as sudo.

Answer (score 4):

Try `sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'` to see where `sudo` is looking for commands; you can then symlink `pip` into one of those directories.

Comment: This is another way to solve my problem, I add /usr/local/bin to secure_path, it also works, thanks

Comment: `$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/bin/pip` is the way I achieved it.

Comment: @MikeiLL, thanks. For what it's worth, I instead found `usr/local/bin/pip3.4` on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

pip can be installed with below command :

`yum -y install python-pip`

If your facing any problem with GPG key (no such file or directory), then trigger below command:

```
rpm --import http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
```

then try install `pip`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `-E` option to `sudo` to use the environmental variables of your user account

```
$ sudo -E pip install xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

On my system, I have miniconda installed; so any terminal I open is initially in the base environment.  To install pip packages globally, I need to "conda deactivate" first, out of the base environment. Then when I "pip install" a package, it can be seen by the system globally.